# What is bootstrap/less/html5?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, less

Someone asked me to cut a design layout using bootstrap/less/html5 and i am not really sure what they mean. I found something related to bootstrap from twitter, but nothing related to less.

Thank you.

Comment: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/, http://lesscss.org

Comment: You have even *tagged* this question with tags you could click on to get more information about what you're asking...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bootstrap is a css framework from twitter . Excellent for frontend prototyping and building robust crossbrowser and mobile friendly websites.

HTML5 Its an improved version of html and is in continuous development for more robustness and usability.

Less is a css preprocessor . It allows you to write css more dynamically providing re-usability and cutting short the time to write and manage large css files .

Links To read more about them :

Bootstrap : http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

HTML5     : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp

Less      : http://lesscss.org

Comment: No longer referred to as Twitter Bootstrap,  just Bootstrap and for Visual Studio 2013 a new MVC 5 app includes Bootstrap.  Now by far the best standard around version 3 is pretty impressive.

Answer (score 4):

Less is a dynamic stylesheet language. You can find it here, [Less](http://lesscss.org/).

Bootstrap is a framework to define web pages. It is very common for the designers because they can produce an HTML/Javascript that is cross-browser, very simple and also ready for the mobile. [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

HTML5 is the most recent standard to define web pages. It is more powerfull than previous versions. If you want to know more, try to search HTML5.

This tools have a lot of features that are impossible to describe here. Check the links, you will learn with no troubles.